# elasticsearch › Problems with eliminating null values from query results

Tags: elasticsearch, null, wildcard

I was working on fetching data from elasticsearch index.
I wanted to filter out documents that contain null or empty string values in certain columns.
Yet when I used either "missing" or "exists" methods I faced some issues with values = "" as they were not filtered out and showed in the results

I thought of using wildcard instead but then it gave no results when dealing with columns that had multiple words in their ID (ex: Alarm Description,Alarm ID,...etc)

Working on elasticsearch-1.3.2

My code with missing/exists :

```
{
   "query" : {
      "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
            "exists" : {
               "field" : "myfield"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

My code with wildcard:

```
{
    query: {
     bool: {
     must: [
{
    constant_score: {
     filter: {
      missing: {
     field: trap_message.enterprise
}
}
}
}
]
     must_not: [ ]
     should: [ ]
}
}
     from: 0
     size: 10
     sort: [ ]
     facets: { }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I switched from GET to POST

Answer (score 0):

I would combine the exists filter with a must_not.  Here is a sample searching the field "authResult.address.state"

```
GET index1/type1/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "exists": {
                 "field": "authResult.address.state"
              }          
            }
          ],
          "must_not": [
             {
                 "term": {
                    "authResult.address.state": ""
                 }
             }
          ]          
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but still I get the same results